# Removing dots in a string in C

Tags: c, character

I'm making a little program in C where I would put in a couple of numbers and dots and then delete all the dots (.).

I was thinking about a whileloop but I cannot seem to quite understand what I should do next. So far I got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char s[30];
int k=0;
printf("Enter your account number including dots. \n");  
gets(s);
printf("Account number without dots:");
while (s[k]!=0) 
    {
       //?????
    }
return 0;
```

Am I on the right track or should I start differently and not use a while loop at all? I can only find solutions where there is a specific string that is not written by the user, but by the programmer...

Comment: You could start by [not using `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html).

Comment: Rule #1 of modern C programming, never ***EVER*** use `gets`.

Comment: Why? Sorry, total noob here.

Comment: @user3163471: Because in your case, if the user enters 30 or more characters, you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: Oh, I see. Will remember that, thanks! Doesn't really matter in this one though since I'm not expecting to write that many characters as input.

Comment: gets will be abolished.

Comment: Also, why are you allowing input to `main` (via `*argv[]`) and then interactively asking for an input number?  Choose one or the other.

Comment: I thought that wouldn't be a problem? I only just started with learning C and have limited knowledge of Java. I'm not really in my element yet when I'm programming...

Comment: @user3163471 You are on the right track. You can probably ignore most of the above comments. They're discussing things that you probably won't encounter, and will probably be important later when you write more complicated programs, but don't matter for now.

Comment: @Xymostech I agree about not worrying about putting `int argc, char ** argv` in `main`'s signature (it's not wrong and not a problem, just slight overkill). But there is no excuse for using `gets` anymore, and one day your simple program might grow into a complex one that gets used by many and then you're going to look really stupid for allowing such a simple buffer-overflow opportunity. It may sound a bit overprotective but this is how some very embarassing bugs occured in big professional software products.

Comment: Hm, all right. I won't touch gets again! Even though it's good to hear I'm on the right track, my state of mind still says different... I can't seem to understand how to continue the whileloop.

Comment: @Kninnug That's fair. I'm just sad that the first 8 comments didn't touch on their original problem. Nothing scares people away from programming like quibbling about little problems. `fgets` is easy to fix though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in an IF to only print characters that aren't a dot. Like the others suggested, you should probably change the gets to fgets as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char s[30];
    int k=0;
    printf("Enter your account number including dots. \n");  
    gets(s);
    printf("Account number without dots:");
    while (s[k]!=0) {
        if ( s[k] != '.' ) {
            printf("%c", s[k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With a while loop, I'm also worried that if the user puts in a full 30 characters, you won't reach your exit condition. To avoid this problem, a for loop would be better (since you already know the size of the array). However, if you do it this way, you'll also need to initialize your array "s" to be blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char s[30];
    int k=0;
    printf("Enter your account number including dots. \n");  
    gets(s);
    printf("Account number without dots:");
    for ( k = 0 ; k < 30 ; k++ ) {
        if ( s[k] != '.' && s[k] != 0 ) {
            printf("%c", s[k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Did not expect anyone to completely make it. I see where you're going to now. The first code you made seemed to work for me. You're just printing everything that's not equal to a dot right? Seems really logical but my mind just wouldn't understand before.

Comment: No problem. You understood it perfectly. If all you want is something quick and dirty, the first code is good enough. However, if you want something a bit more robust, I'd work off of the second code. I really don't like the idea of going through an array of known size with a while loop. If you add a small loop to initialize "s[]" to 0, the second code should work perfectly as well.

Comment: All right, will experiment some more with it. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you might go at it - it's different from how you've started, but can easily be modified.  It could be improved on as well, but we can quibble about that in further comments.  :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* Take account number in as argument to executable */

  int dotless_length = 30;
  char dotless[dotless_length];
  int k = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (argv[1][k] != '\0' && i < dotless_length) {
    if (argv[1][k] >= 48 && argv[1][k] <= 57) { /* ascii decimal codes for 0-9 */
      dotless[i] = argv[1][k];
      i++;
    }
    else if (argv[1][k] != '.') {
      printf("invalid input:  %c\n", argv[1][k]);
      return 1;
    }
    k++;
  }

  dotless[i] = '\0'; /* null-terminate it! */

  printf("Account number without dots: %s\n", dotless);

  return 0;
}
```

Then compile with `gcc -Wall -o zdotless filename.c` and run with

`./zdotless 401.863.3000` as an example.

**Notes**:  This may look more harder since it goes into input sanitation (and cleanliness) a little more than your original - e.g.

1. not assuming that user input consists solely of numbers and periods,
2. saving the resulting dotless string (for presumable future manipulations?),
3. having one place to change the length of `dotless` (a step towards not hardcoding it), and
4. not being interactive.

When you call an executable, `argv` is what you've typed, so `argv[0]` is the executable name (`./zdotless`), `argv[1]` is the next argument (`401.863.3000` as a string), and so on if there are more arguments.  Since `argv[1]` is the string representation of your dotty input number, `argv[1][0]` is the first character of it, etc.

Since we're copying to `dotless` character-by-character rather than using string manipulation, you've got to tack on a null character manually.  (That same null character is what you'd loop until reaching, when initially reading the input string.) Other questions?...

Comment: Also, is there a strong reason to use C?  If it's a once-off thing, a shell script could make quick work of it, e.g. `echo "401.863.258130901" | sed -E 's/\.//g'`

Comment: I just really want to learn C so I can get into embedded stuff. I'm trying to find assignments all around to excersise with. Your code seems harder than it could be though? I seem to follow most of it but I'm a bit off track at 'argv[1][k]' Also why do you use those ascii decimal codes if I may ask?

Comment: Cool!  I've added some explanations, but feel free to ask about other things that aren't clear!  Also, the ascii character codes aren't necessary(?) though there may be some esoteric arguments about this.

Comment: Awesome, couldn't ask for more! If only I knew people on this forum were so eager to help before haha. Thank you so much, I really appreciate you taking time for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char s[30];
int k=0;
printf("Enter your account number including dots. \n");  
gets(s);
printf("Account number without dots:");
while (s[k]!=0) 
    {
       if(s[k] == '.')
          s[k] = s[k + 1];
       k++;
    }
    s[k] = '\0';
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

//remove the specified character from str
char *strrmc(char *str, char ch){
    char *from, *to;
    from = to = str;
    while(*from){
        if(*from == ch)
            ++from;
        else
            *to++ = *from++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char s[30] = "192.169.007";
    printf("%s\n", strrmc(s, '.'));//192169007
    return 0;
}
```